# Getting a 'slide down' js panel implemented within WP

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

**I'm trying to implement a very simple vertical slide down panel in Wordpress,** I've tried jbar *(http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/29/jbar-a-jquery-notification-plugin/)* and an easy JS method I found at http://jsfiddle.net/ahr3U/

But I still cannot get this implemented, I've tried inserting the below code in the *footer.php* right before it's close, and within the *header.php* and still nothing appears.

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#notification").addClass("visible");
    });

    </script>
```

**And CSS:**

```
#notification {
background-color: #F00;
color: #FFF;
height: 25px;
position: absolute;
top: -25px;
width: 100%;
transition: top 0.5s;
-moz-transition: top 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: top 0.5s;
-o-transition: top 0.5s;
```

}

```
#notification.visible {
top: 0px;
```

}

**The HTML CTA via the div, I've tried calling with the** `<head>` **and** `<body>`

```
<div id="notification">Page load complete...</div>
```

Comment: Where is this supposed to appear? In the WP admin panel? In every page of the WP site? Can you clarify the question a little bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the script code in the  and make sure you close the first script tag where you include the jquery library

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, going to try this now - didn't realize it could have such an impact.

Comment: yeah, if the markup can't be decoded it wont render on the browser. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: So it's implemented now. BUT, the above the fold area is blank upon page load. When you scroll below the 'above-the-fold' and then scroll back up, the content there appears. Weirdest thing ever. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your 'above the fold area'? Is that the same as the example of 'notifications'? Do you have a link to what you are doing, or jfiddle? I'm not sure what you are saying.

I'm glad that script tag fix worked. don't forget to mark as answer and +1 :)

Comment: BLAH - it was a confliction with other plugins I had implemented, once deactivated, boom.